# Get the Monday and Sunday for a certain DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, date

I have a for example the date "**2010-11-09, Thuesday**"

Now I want to get the datetime of the Monday and Sunday wherein lies the above stated date.

How would you do that?

Comment: @Lisa; you mean you want the dates of the Monday and Sunday that are in the week of that Tuesday?

Comment: @Beemer: With the convention that the week starts on Sunday that wouldn't work.

Comment: @Hank; yes it would. OP may want to retrieve the Sunday that starts the week of the Tuesday. Any logic is possible so long as we don't know what exactly they want.  Check answer below by poster "light" that does that.

Comment: @Henk I meant between MOnday and SUnday.

Comment: @Lisa: I thought so but dates are synonymous with culturally dependent definitions and conventions. It pays to be clear.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is probaly what you're after:

```
 DateTime date = DateTime.Today;

 // lastMonday is always the Monday before nextSunday.
 // When date is a Sunday, lastMonday will be tomorrow.     
 int offset = date.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday;     
 DateTime lastMonday = date.AddDays(-offset);
 DateTime nextSunday = lastMonday.AddDays(6);
```

Edit: since `lastMonday` is not always what the name suggests (see the comments), the following one-liner is probably more to the point:

```
 DateTime nextSunday = date.AddDays(7 - (int) date.DayOfWeek);
```

Comment: nice solution, much cleaner than mine.

Comment: This has two errors, a typo on Monday.AddDays.. should be lowercase 'm' for monday. Also to get sunday from monday you would add 6 days not 7. Adding seven days gives you the following Monday.

Comment: This has another error. If Today is a Sunday, it will return next Monday (offset = -1) instead of last Monday. Cast as an integer Sunday will return 0 and Monday will return 1, so Sunday - Monday = -1.

Adding this line, will fix it:
offset = (offset < 0) ? 6 : offset;

Comment: @gijswijs - You're right, but do note that lastMonday was meant as an intermediate, my code does produce the correct nextSunday for a sunday  (- -1 + 6 = +7).  So in hindsight, `lastMonday` was badly named.

Answer (score 1):

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the day that is the specific day of week of the input day.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="input">The input day.</param>
/// <param name="dayOfWeek">0 is Monday, 6 is Sunday.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static DateTime GetDayOfWeekOfSpecific(DateTime input, int dayOfWeek)
{
    if(input.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        dayOfWeek -= 7;
    }
    // lastMonday is always the Monday before nextSunday.
    // When today is a Sunday, lastMonday will be tomorrow.     
    int offset = input.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday;
    DateTime lastMonday = input.AddDays(-offset);
    DateTime nextDayOfWeek = lastMonday.AddDays(dayOfWeek);
    return nextDayOfWeek;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, of course you would want to break from the loop at some point before the DateTime.MaxValue, but this should do:

```
  DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2010-11-09, Thuesday");


        while (dt < DateTime.MaxValue) 
        {

            if(dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday || dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
                Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString());
            dt.AddDays(1);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> DateTime Monday =
>   DateTime.Now.AddDays((DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek
>   - 1) * -1).Date;
>
> DateTime Sunday =
>   DateTime.Now.AddDays(7
>   -DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek).Date;

Comment: I don't think this works on Sunday.  Wouldn't you get Tomorrow and next Sunday which wouldn't bound Today (Sunday)?  (0-1)*-1 = 1, 7-0 = 7.

Answer (score -1):

It's easily if you use a conditional method

```
if (v_datetime.DayOfWeek== DayOfWeek.Sunday)
{
return true;
}

if (v_datetime.DayOfWeek== DayOfWeek.Monday)
{

}
```

Comment: please update your answer to provide a full answer to the original question rather than just responding to someone's comment.