# U-SQL: select Monday this week and Monday previous week

Tags: date, u-sql

How do I select in U-SQL Monday of this week and Monday of the week before?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since the expression language in U-SQL is C#, you can use C# expressions. The following stackoverflow thread shows some examples:

[Get the Monday and Sunday for a certain DateTime in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139287/get-the-monday-and-sunday-for-a-certain-datetime-in-c-sharp)